# Помогите составить программу которая выводит все простые числа через запятую до целого числа веденный на клавиатуре

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Введите положительное число: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = in.nextInt();
            boolean b = true;
            for (int P = 1; P <= input; P++) {
                for (int i = 1; i < P; i++)
                {
                    if (P % i == 0){
                        b = false;
                    }
                    System.out.println(P);}
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: А что , программа не работает?

Comment: выводит не через запятыю

Comment: Так выведите ещё и запятую. Но я вижу более серьезную проблему, вы b для чего-то приготовили, но не используете, а надо.

Comment: можешь подсказать как должно работать с б

Answer (score 0):

```
b=true
```

внутри первого цикла, а выводить P после проверки b

```
  if(b)...
```

Comment: @ProSet Помогло?